# Match Multiple Line Regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, multiline

I have beat my head against the wall for the better part of the night so I am looking to the stackoverflow Gods to help with this.  I have a text string that I am attempting to parse into an array. See the example below:

```
Name: John Doe
Address: 123 W Main Street
City: Denver


Name: Julie Smith
Address: 1313 Mockingbird Lane
City: Burbank
```

What I would like to get is an array that looks like this:

```
[Name: John Doe Address: 123 W Main Street City: Denver, Name: Julie Smith Address 1313 Mockingbird Lane City: Burbank]
```

I started with the following regex and it works fine in regexpal:

```
(Name.+)(\n.*){2}
```

However, when I try to use that in my program or even jsfiddle, I get a null return:

http://jsfiddle.net/auqHA/1/

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want in the array? Do you want an array of `"Key: Value"` strings? Do you want a dictionary where you can access `"Value"` by `"Key"`?

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/zV8uA6) ?

Comment: @KendallFrey I'm actually just going to then use the array elements as a string to pass along to another function which I have already written to parse it further and process the information.

Comment: @HamZa that broke it down into too many elements, any way we can just throw the three lines together in one array element?

Comment: @NeverHopeless that is a sample, but there is more of the data, that has space in it, so thanks for the idea, but I don't think that will work this time around...

Comment: @user2451775 I think you should _split_ by [several new lines](http://regex101.com/r/zR1aX6) and then loop through your array and remove new lines.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use *JavaScript's* [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with
`/(?:Name.+)(?:\n.*){2}/g`. The non-capture groups are so you don't double up your results.

```
var s = '\
Name: John Doe\n\
Address: 123 W Main Street\n\
City: Denver\n\
\n\
\n\
Name: Julie Smith\n\
Address: 1313 Mockingbird Lane\n\
City: Burbank\
';

var arr = s.match(/(?:Name.+)(?:\n.*){2}/g);
/* gives
["Name: John Doe\n\
Address: 123 W Main Street\n\
City: Denver", "Name: Julie Smith\n\
Address: 1313 Mockingbird Lane\n\
City: Burbank"]
*/
// so if you want no new lines,
arr.map(function (e) {return e.replace(/\n/g, ' ');});
```

---

**Edit** Just looked at your fiddle, the reason it doesn't work is because you forgot to put in new lines. i.e.

```
s = 'a\
b'; // s === "ab"

s = 'a\n\
b'; // s === "a\nb"
```

Comment: Thanks Paul...still running into issues but getting a lot closer!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a JS expert but after a bit of work around i can offer this script:

```
var rawdata='\
\
\
Name: John Doe\
Address: 123 W Main Street\
City: Denver\
\
\
Name: Julie Smith\
Address: 1313 Mockingbird Lane\
City: Burbank';

var looppattern = /Name: /g;
var loopnum = rawdata.match(looppattern);

var pattern = /\s{2}([\w\:\s]+)/;
var nummessages = rawdata.replace(new RegExp("Name:", 'g'),"{Name:").split("{");

alert(nummessages[1]);
alert(nummessages[2]);
```

which seems to work in JSFiddle. Here i supposed '{' does not lie in between the string you can change this delimiter.